# Solve the equation $\sin(5x) - \sin(3x) = \sqrt2/2$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm stuck on this problem and can't get any clue to solve this. Please help me, thanks.

> > Solve the equation: $\sin(5x) - \sin(3x) = \sqrt2/2$

Thanks, I really appreciate if some one can help me.

Comment: $\sin A-\sin B=?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\sin x-\sin y=2\sin\frac{x-y}2\cos\frac{x+y}2\implies$$

$$\sin5x-\sin3x=2\sin x\cos4x$$

But remember that also

$$\cos2y=\begin{cases}\cos^2y-\sin^2y\\{}\\{}2\cos^2y-1\\{}\\1-2\sin^2y\end{cases}$$

Comment: So sorry, I make a mistake in the problem. The right side expression is $\sqrt2/2$. I follow what you suggest, but I got a 5-degree equation. How can I solve this?

Comment: @leducquang, you should have posted till which step you were able to solve the problem.